# What path should be for a HTTP listner in Mule 4

Tags: mule4, raml

I am new to Mule soft and I want to access below URLs using a path value in Mule 4. Below are the URLs.

http://localhost:8082/customer/status
http://localhost:8082/order/status

Comment: Please add more details on what is the issue, what are you trying to achieve and what you have tried. It is not clear if you want to make an HTTP request or configure an HTTP Listener. It is not obvious what is the correct path since we can not know your API implementation. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: Also note that MuleSoft is a company name, and Mule 4 is the product that can execute Mule applications. There is no 'mulesoft 4'.